# Pulling information from Propertybase.com

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to create a native iOS application that will pull information from propertybase.com which is based on salesforce. I can't seem to find a public access web service or API.

Hope someone here can direct me to the correct path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried 14-day free trial?   That's probably the best thing to do, and I'm sure they will have support staff which can provide the necessary tech docs.

http://www.propertybase.com/sign-up

I would also guess that you would be able to leverage the partner WSDL or APIs once you have the proper credentials.  It looks like a specialized version of SFDC, but should run on the same APIs as any other SFDC